# PHP my admin to connect with Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, amazon-rds

hello I am trying to connect `phpMyAdmin` to Amazon RDS. I am successfully connecting the mysql through terminal like this

mysql -h xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com -u myusername -p

and for phpmyadmin I am doing this in **config.inc.php** file

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'myusername';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'mypassword';
```

The problem I am having is If I do this and access the phpmyadmin, My phpmyadmin shows like this
[image]

It doesn't show tables columns or anything on the left side. But If I remove this code then everything is back to normal meaning I can see tables

Comment: Back to normal means are you able to see tables and columns on left side after you remove the code?

Comment: So what is exactly issue here if you are able to see the table and columns after you remove the code?

Comment: well the problem is If I create database here directly in phpmyadmin then It doesn't show up on terminal if I write this command
mysql> show databases.

Comment: because PHPMy admin is not connected to the RDS. due to that I can't connect the database to my website

Comment: if you are fortunate enough to have RDS, why are you using phpmyadmin with it?

Comment: okay how can I see my database or import database. I need some gui for it or you have some better idea to import my existing database

Comment: Use MYSQL workbench

Comment: @hellosheikh, in you PMA config are you specifying root user credentials ? if credentials are correct make sure that you open access to your RDS instance from the server where PMA is installed